# Menu PopOver IOS Swift

Tags: swift, popover

Estou tentado fazer um menu `PopOver` semelhante o do `WhatsApp` mas sem sucesso. Queria fazer um menu semelhante ao abaixo.
[image: menu]

O único menu `PopOver` que consigo fazer é com o fundo branco e ocupa a tela inteira, mesmo sendo `PopOver`.

Comment: Poste o código para facilitar a resposta.

Comment: com dito pelo amigo @rubStackOverflow posta o codigo de como ta chamando esse popover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa implementar na verdade se chama UIAlertController:

```
func displayAlertMenu() {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Selecione a origem", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Tirar Foto ou Filmar Video", style: .default) {
        action in
        // call display camera method
    }

    let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Escolher Foto Existente", style: .default) {
        action in
        // call display gallery method
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .cancel) {
        action in
        print("user tapped the cancel button")
    }

    alert.addAction(cameraAction)
    alert.addAction(galleryAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

E chame o metodo quando a sua view aparecer ou ao apertar de um botão:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    displayAlertMenu()
}
```